# Find the number of distinct triplets sums to a given integer

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

You have been given a random integer array/list(ARR) and a number X. Find and return the number of distinct triplet(s) in the array/list which sum to X.

I have written this code:

```
public class Solution { 
    public static void merge(int arr[], int lb, int mid, int ub) {
        int n1 = mid - lb + 1;
        int n2 = ub - mid;
 
        int arr1[] = new int[n1];
        int arr2[] = new int[n2];
 
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            arr1[i] = arr[lb + i];

        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            arr2[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
 
        int i = 0, j = 0;
 
        int k = lb;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j])
                arr[k] = arr1[i++];
            else
                arr[k] = arr2[j++];

            k++;
        }
 
        while (i < n1)
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
 
        while (j < n2)
            arr[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
    
    public static void mergeSort(int arr[], int lb, int ub) {
        if (lb < ub) {
            int mid = lb + (ub - lb) / 2;
 
            mergeSort(arr, lb, mid);
            mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ub);
            merge(arr, lb, mid, ub);
        }
    }

    public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1); 
        int n = arr.length;
        int count = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
            int sum = num - arr[i];
            
            int j = i + 1;
            int k = n - 1;
            while (j < k) {
                if (arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) {
                    count++;
                    k--;
                } else if (arr[j] + arr[k] > sum) {
                    k--;
                } else
                    j++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Input array was - `1 3 3 3 3 3 3`

Input num = `9`

Output Generated - `10`

Expected output - `20`

Help me out with this I'm trying to find the solution for many hours. Also, the time complexity of the program should not exceed O(n²).

Comment: Please, provide the code template they provide

Comment: If the input is `n` 3's and the goal is 9, the solution is `nC3 = n(n-1)(n-2) / 3!`. This is a cubic expression in `n`. The method of counting 1 for each iteration is `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The given code works fine for all test cases.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Solution {

    public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int n = arr.length;
        
        int Numtripletsum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int pairSumFor = num - arr[i];
            int numPairs = pairSum(arr, (i+1), (n-1), pairSumFor);
            Numtripletsum+=numPairs;
        }
        return Numtripletsum;
        
    }
    private static int pairSum(int[] arr, int startIndex, int endIndex, int num ){
        
        int numPair = 0;
        while(startIndex < endIndex){
            if(arr[startIndex] + arr[endIndex] < num){
                startIndex++;
            }
            else if(arr[startIndex] + arr[endIndex] > num){
                endIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                int elementAtStart = arr[startIndex];
                int elementAtEnd = arr[endIndex];
                
                if(elementAtStart == elementAtEnd){
                    int totalElementsFromStartToEnd = (endIndex - startIndex) + 1;
                    numPair += (totalElementsFromStartToEnd * (totalElementsFromStartToEnd -1) /2);
                    
                    return numPair;
                }
                int tempStartIndex = startIndex + 1;
                int tempEndIndex = endIndex - 1;
                
                while(tempStartIndex <= tempEndIndex && arr[tempStartIndex] == elementAtStart){
                    tempStartIndex+=1;
                }
                while(tempEndIndex >= tempStartIndex && arr[tempEndIndex] == elementAtEnd){
                    tempEndIndex-=1;
                }
                int totalElementsFromStart = (tempStartIndex - startIndex);
                int totalElementsFromEnd = (endIndex - tempEndIndex);
                
                numPair += (totalElementsFromStart * totalElementsFromEnd);
                
                startIndex = tempStartIndex;
                endIndex = tempEndIndex;
            }
        }
        return numPair;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way, hope I understood it well.

```
public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
    int loops = 0; // just to check the quality of the code
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < arr.length - 2; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < arr.length - 1; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = i2 + 1; i3 < arr.length; i3++) {
                loops++;
                if (arr[i1] + arr[i2] + arr[i3] == num) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Check for not exceeding O(n^2)
    if (loops <= arr.length * arr.length) {
        System.io.println("Well done");
    } else {
        System.io.println("Too many cycles");
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I iterate from "left" to "right" over the array and walking more and more to the "right".

```
1st, 2nd, 3rd
1st, 2nd, 4th
...
1st, 2nd, nth
2nd, 3rd, 4th
2nd, 3rd, 5th
...
2nd, 3rd, nth
.
.
.
nth - 2, nth - 1, nth
```

I iterated 35 times, but could iterate 7^2 = 49 times --> "Well done"

Comment: Facing Time Limit Issues with this approach.

Comment: Yes, when there are more than 8 numbers in the array, my code is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You missed one loop. The fixed code:

```
    public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
    //Your code goes here
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    int n = arr.length;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
        int sum = num - arr[i];
        
        for (int j = i+1; j < n-1; j++) {
            int k = n-1;
            while (j < k) {
                if (arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) {
                    count++;
                    k--;
                } else if (arr[j] + arr[k] > sum) {
                    k--;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Getting an error of Time Limit Exceeded for some test cases. The time complexity of the program should be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

OK, then optimized version:

```
public static int tripletSum(int[] arr, int num) {
    //Your code goes here
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    int n = arr.length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
        int sum = num - arr[i];

        int maxK = n - 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            int k = maxK;

            while (j < k) {
                if (arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) {
                    count++;
                    k--;
                } else if (arr[j] + arr[k] > sum) {
                    k--;
                    maxK--;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the efforts. But I'm now getting wrong answers in some test cases. I have found the solution and also posted it.